# 7 segment LEDs on wood face

Tags: led, display

I'm not sure this is right place for this question, but does anyone have any idea how a 7 segment display is projected or embedded in wood for products like this?

[image: amazon wood clock]

Full product info at [http://www.amazon.com/Cube-Wood-LED-Alarm-Clock/dp/B00D6DI0LE](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00D6DI0LE)

Another example:

[image]

From: http://www.selectism.com/2013/11/27/a-wooden-led-alarm-clock-and-wireless-bluetooth-speaker-from-gogroove/

Comment: Those examples are computer generated. In reality the contrast is a bit less, and the outlines aren't as sharp. But it's still a very cool effect.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is done by carefully placing a layer of wood veneer over the 7-segment displays. The veneer is thin enough to let the light pass through. I wouldn't be surprised if some manufacturers use brighter than normal LEDs to make the display easier to see. [Here is a video detailing an example.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2P-8-zd7sXg)

It is also possible to simply drill out the wood to make it very thin where the 7-segment displays go. [Here is an example of drilling the solid wood to be very thin.](http://www.instructables.com/id/Solid-Wood-Digital-Clock/)